# Delete duplicate records base on time inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know, there are lot of q & a for this. But it doesn't return the right answer. I have here sample result of the table. There are lots of data in the table. But I need to delete the duplicate records with same status, col1, col2, col3 and createdon has only differences in minutes/seconds.

This is my query to get the duplicate records..

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        IssueID AS id, CallID, StatusID AS [status], 
        LevelOneIRCID AS col1, LevelTwoIRCID AS col2, 
        LevelThreeIRCID AS col3, CreatedOn, 
        AddedByUserID AS updatedon, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY statusid, leveloneircid, leveltwoircid, levelthreeircid, businessunitone, businessunittwo, businessunitthree, Remarks, AddedByUserID --, CreatedOn
                               ORDER BY  leveloneircid, LevelTwoIRCID, LevelThreeIRCID, BusinessUnitOne, BusinessUnitTwo, BusinessUnitThree, Remarks)  
    FROM 
        dbo.Issues 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn > 1;
```

But when I add the createdon inside partition by, it does not count as duplicate since in has differences in seconds.. but I need to consider that condition. How am I supposed to do? HELP PLEASE

[image]

Comment: change created on to some thing like cast(createdon as date)

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar, will try that

Comment: hi @TheGameiswar, is there any way to cast date but remove the seconds?

Comment: @TheGameiswar has posted it earler. Use that insetad of just createdon in your partition by query

Answer (score 0):

Please try similar to this (Diff of Max and MIN of 'Createdon' and Group by required columns)

```
SELECT  status, col1, col2, col3, datediff(hour,MAX(CreatedOn),MIN(CreatedOn)) AS diff
FROM dbo.Issues 
GROUP BY status, col1, col2, col3
HAVING datediff(hour,MAX(CreatedOn),MAX(CreatedOn)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        IssueID AS id, CallID, StatusID AS [status], 
        LevelOneIRCID AS col1, LevelTwoIRCID AS col2, 
        LevelThreeIRCID AS col3, CreatedOn, 
        AddedByUserID AS updatedon, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StatusID, LevelOneIRCID, LevelTwoIRCID, LevelThreeIRCID 
                               ORDER BY  CreatedOn)  
    FROM 
        dbo.Issues 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Use `CreatedOn` in `Order By`. The `PARTITION BY` set to your future unique keys - `StatusID, LevelOneIRCID, LevelTwoIRCID, LevelThreeIRCID` . I assumed that your query was OK.